# Trying to make a pop appear up when the wrong password is enterd Kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

When I enter the right password it does what I want, it goes to the next screen. When I enter the wrong password it does not go to the next screen just like I want but, it throws an error when the pop is supposed to appear.

This is the App code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import mainthread
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup



Builder.load_file('main.kv')


class Menu(BoxLayout):
   manager = ObjectProperty(None)


class ScreenLogIn(Screen):

  @mainthread
  def verify_credentials(self):

    try:


        if self.ids.login.text == "email@email.com" and self.ids.passw.text == "password":
            self.manager.current = "match"
        else:
            popup = Popup(title='Wrong',
                          content='Wrong Email/Password')
            popup.open()
    except Exception as e:
        pass


class ScreenNearUsers(Screen):

    @mainthread
    def on_enter(self):
      for i in xrange(101):
          button = Button(text="B_" + str(i))
          self.ids.grid.add_widget(button)


class ScreenMatch(Screen):
   pass


class ScreenChats(Screen):
   pass


class ScreenUserProfile(Screen):
  pass


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    screen_log_in = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_near_user = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_match = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_chats = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_user_profile = ObjectProperty(None)


class MenuApp(App):

   def build(self):
      return Menu()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MenuApp().run()`
```

The main.kv:

```
#get login screen working
<Menu>:
   manager: screen_manager
   orientation: "vertical"
   id: action
   ActionBar:
       size_hint_y: 0.1
       background_color: 0, 0, 35, 2
       background_normal: ""
       ActionView:
           ActionPrevious:
           ActionButton:
                id: near_users
                icon: 'icons/internet.png'
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'near_users'
           ActionButton:
               id: matching
               text: "Matching"
               on_press: root.manager.current= 'match'
           ActionButton:
               id: chat
               text: "chat"
               on_press: root.manager.current = 'chats'
           ActionButton:
               id: profile
               text: "Profile"
               on_press: root.manager.current = 'profile'
   Manager:
      id: screen_manager

<ScreenLogIn>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    id: login_screen
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: login
        TextInput:
            id: passw
            password: True # hide password
        Button:
            text: "Log In"
            on_release: root.verify_credentials()

<ScreenNearUsers>:
     ScrollView:
         GridLayout:
            id: grid
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            cols: 2
            row_default_height: '20dp'
            row_force_default: True
            spacing: 0, 0
            padding: 0, 0

<ScreenMatch>:
    Button:
        text:
<ScreenChats>:
    Button:
        text: "stuff3"
<ScreenUserProfile>:
    Button:
        text: "stuff4"

<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager
    screen_log_in: screen_log_in
    screen_near_users: screen_near_users
    screen_match: screen_match
    screen_chats: screen_chats
    screen_user_profile: screen_user_profile

ScreenLogIn:
    id: screen_log_in
    name: 'login'
    manager: screen_manager
ScreenNearUsers:
    id: screen_near_users
    name: 'near_users'
    manager: screen_manager
ScreenMatch:
    id: screen_match
    name: 'match'
    manager: screen_manager
ScreenChats:
    id: screen_chats
    name: 'chats'
    manager: screen_manager
ScreenUserProfile:
    id: screen_user_profile
    name: 'profile'
    manger: screen_manager
```

The error:

> [WARNING]  have                   no cols or rows set, layout is not triggered.

Comment: show main.kv please

Comment: Sorry, I did not think it was needed I will edit and add it.

Comment: the error is caused by a layout, and probably the error is in the .kv, even if it was not that you must provide a [mcve], that is, a verifiable code, and if it can not be executed it is not verifiable, read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: I added the main.kv

Comment: I think the `content` of your `Popup` should be a `Widget`, not just a string. Perhaps a `Label`.

Comment: That worked thank you.